# Regex without negative lookahead for Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm having trouble declaring a regex for my Funnel in Google Analytics. As Google Analytics won't accept negative lookahead regex I'm looking for a solution for this regex:

```
^/(en/)?((?!signin|login|signup|content|info|about-us|blog|impressum)[^/])+(\?|\Z)
```

With custom segments I can exclude the pages, but using the regex in the funnel I need a include regex. Is there any way to convert above regex to and include regex?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're going for, but you can't include data after you excluded it from your dataset - what seems to be the thing you're after. Unless I'm wrong, of course, in which case: could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve *exactly*?